# Firebug report is blank for a period of time... (performance improvement)

Tags: performance, optimization, firebug, performance-testing

I am trying to optimize my webpage using firebug on firfox. However, i am puzzled by the Net report generated for this page : http://67.20.122.201/boikeno/ebookindex.php?isbn=9781429960625&title=Red%20Dragon%20Rising:%20Edge%20of%20War

There seems to be a period of no activity on this report (no javascript seems to be getting uploaded during this period either)

Any help would be highly appreciated. I am following instructions given here to optimize this page:
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload#DeferLoadingJS

[image: Net Panel page report]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the last component fetched in the main sequence (on the left) is the Javascript through your combine.php handler ([link](http://67.20.122.201/boikeno/assets/js/combine.php?fileHeader=bottom)). So, the delay is likely due to the browser parsing that Javascript (which is probably pretty quick), and then any time spent by the script itself.

Comment: Thanks @brianc any suggestion on how can i potenitally reduce the time taken by the script